# Power query order of queries

Tags: excel, powerquery

I would like to know if it is possible to control the execution order of queries in PQ.
Let me explain, i run:

- A procedure that I named "executer_procedure"
- I display a table that has been modified by the previous procedure that I named "Requete 1"

So, it is essential for me that "executer_procedure" is executed before "Requete 1".
Is it possible to create a new query with "executer_procedure" and then "Requete 1" ?

I tried to encapsulate the procedure in my second request but it doesn't work. The procedure does not run (I did the test by clearing the data from the table to see if the procedure updates it well).

I show you a screenshot of the dependencies of my queries.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbUkF.png)

I searched the internet for resources but couldn't find an answer ...
On Excel, using VBA I can update the queries in the order I want but I don't want to use VBA in my projects ...

Is this possible under PQ?
Thank you.

Saigon

Comment: See [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/power-query-refresh-order/m-p/1015868). But I don't know how definitive it is.

Comment: There is other information involving use of the `Invoke.After` function.

Comment: Thank you ! I will look at it ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I integrated my procedure into my 2nd query so it runs well before displaying my table.
This is the solution (and I have searched in different forums) that I have found to not include vba code in my project, without complicating my file
If it can help anyone ...
Thank you for your time :)